# Insert Multiple Values > One Column from POST Form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with this select:

```
<select name="territory[]"><option vaue="None Selected">Please Select</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
// And so on...
</select>
```

Next to the select option is a button where they can add another country with the same select options.  Now when they submit I want them to go into one column in the database called COUNTRIES.  So if a person selects 3 countries such as Argentina, Australia and New Zealand, they will display in the database column countries like:

```
COUNTRIES
------------------
Argentina, Australia, New Zealand
```

I have been looking and UNION has popped up but I am unsure how to use this as other fields are single entries.

```
INSERT into b_project (NAME,COUNTRIES, CLIENT) 
VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[countries]','$_POST[client]')
```

I have done it before where I have inserted them onto new rows in the table using:

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $index => $id) 
Then the insert statement with '".$_POST['countries'][$index]."'
```

But I need all the values in one column.  Your advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$countries = implode(',', $_POST['countries']);`

Answer (score 0):

The simple (but a workaround) answer:

```
$countries = implode(',', $_POST['countries']);
```

This will glue the countries with a comma.

The way you should do it:

Use another table in your table, in which you provide all the countries.
Then when a user submits the form, you need another table which map the country_id with the b_project_id. For each country you will have a record in that table.

It little bit more work, but that's the way it should be done.

Last piece of advice:
Please sanitize the inputs. You do not know for sure what a user will send with the POST data. It can be everything...

Comment: Yes I thought about doing it the second way, creating a table for the countries.  I feel this would be the best way and then map to the project table through project ID